# Conditional PHP for @media queries - what are the options?

Tags: php, javascript, conditional-statements, media-queries

I'm creating a web app for android and iOS devices, and using [iScroll 4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) for the ui.

The layout of the app slightly changes between mobile and tablet screen size devices.

Currently I'm using PHP to change the [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) script when on different sections of the site. See below...

```
<script>

    <?php if (is_home()) { ?> // if is home page

    var myScroll,
        myScrollSidebar,
        myScrollHome;

    <?php } else { ?> // else use this

    var myScroll,
        myScrollSidebar;

    <?php } ?>

    function loaded() {

        myScroll = new iScroll('content');
        myScrollSidebar = new iScroll('sidebar');

        <?php if (is_home()) { ?> // if is home page only

        myScrollHome = new iScroll('home', {
            snap: 'li',
            momentum: false,
            hScrollbar: false,
        });

        <?php } ?>

    }

    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { setTimeout(loaded, 200); }, false);

</script>
```

This works!

For tablet size devices, I'm using this media query in my CSS, this covers landscape and portrait mode. See below...

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px)
```

This is also cool.

My problem is - on tablet screen size devices, I need two scrollers for my side bar, replacing the current single sidebar scroller 'myScrollSidebar'

**So I need to change the iScroll script above from this...**

```
var myScrollSidebar;

myScrollSidebar = new iScroll('sidebar');
```

**to this...**

```
var myScrollSidebarLeft,
    myScrollSidebarRight;

myScrollSidebarLeft = new iScroll('sidebar-left');
myScrollSidebarRight = new iScroll('sidebar-right');
```

**when on devices with min-device-width: 768px and max-device-width: 1024px.**

I'm currently using [modernizer's](http://www.modernizr.com/) test : media query with [yep/nope](http://yepnopejs.com/) script loader. See below.

```
<script>
    yepnope({
        test : Modernizr.mq('only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px)'),
        yep  : 'js/tablet.js',
        nope : 'js/mobile.js'

</script>
```

This works perfect for my jquery and javascripts, but for some reason, if I load my [iScroll 4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) script using yep/nope, the iScroll script fails to work.

I've also looked into user agent conditional PHP, using [Detect Mobile Browsers](http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/) PHP script, see below.

```
require_once('php/mobile_device_detect.php');
$iPad = mobile_device_detect(false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false);

<?php if ($iPad==true) { ?>

    // iPad Stuff here...

<?php } ?>
```

This is fine if you only want to detect iPads. My problem is that I need to conditionally change my iScroll script by screen size, as I am accommodating Android tablets too.

Any ideas or pointers would be most awesome. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have that much experience with mobile web development, but to me this whole solution seems like overkill. If you preemptively detect devices and send them modified resources, you will have no end to the headache of trying to scale up the website in the future.

Comment: It's painful I know, but what other way is there when building web apps using one cms. From my experience with user agent based theme redirection plugins, they seem to always leave some devices out - so CSS media queries seems like a safer bet to cover all devices. What do you mean by scale up exactly?

Comment: When you conditionally rewrite the content of a resource, it removes the ability for caches in between you and your client (including in-browser ones) to reason about the content. You'll end up with weird bugs that are hard to track down, and because you can't cache, you've got to have hardware to front the cost of the transaction __on every request__ from a client device.